# xmpp ios : which xmpp delegate to use to get chat notifications (XMPPMessage+XEP_0085)

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am implementing XMPP in my ios app. I am aware of `XMPPMessage+XEP_0085` category which has a few simple methods like `addActiveChatState`, `addComposingChatState` and a few others. I want to show chat notifications e.g. when user is typing a message or paused. I am using following code to send message:

```
  NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:user];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:messageID];

    [message addChild:body];
    [message addChild:setting];

    // chat notifications
    XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
    [xmppMessage addActiveChatState];
    [xmppMessage addComposingChatState];
    [xmppMessage addPausedChatState];
    [xmppMessage addInactiveChatState];
    [xmppMessage addGoneChatState];

    [_appDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:xmppMessage];
```

In which xmpp delegate I should receive these notifications. I am not receiving chat notifications in

```
- (XMPPMessage *)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vitalyster is correct to an extent. This is what I have followed to receive typing notifications properly:

1. After setting up your XMPPMessage, add chatMarkable to the message:

   XMPPMessage *xmppMessage = [XMPPMessage messageFromElement:message];
   [xmppMessage addMarkableChatMarker];

and then send new xmppMessage object.

1. When receiving notification, check if message contains `hasInactiveChatState` or `hasComposingChatState` and handle the UI part accordingly.

You guys might need to add some checks according to the project requirement and handling the typing notifications.

Comment: If this was the perfect solution for what you have asked in the question, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise please share the solution here, so that it will be very helpful for anyone comes here. :)

Comment: The XMPP [Docs](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0333.html) say to this: "WARNING: Consideration of this document has been Deferred by the XMPP Standards Foundation. Implementation of the protocol described herein is not recommended."

Comment: @Sourabh  I'm a beginner in XMPP, I want to implement message seen status and typing status in my app. Can you please explain me, How can i manage it using Markable message?

Comment: @Sweeta  For typing notifications follow below:- 

- Add `addComposingChatState` for sending typing-started notification and add `addInactiveChatState` for typing-stopped notification. 

- On the receiver end, check for `hasComposingChatState` for receiving typing-started notification and `hasInactiveChatState` for receiving typing-stopped notification.

Comment: @Sourabh Thanks for great help, It's working for me. Now, I'm facing problem with Message seen functionality. I'm trying with *addMarkableChatMarker*, But, Can't understand how it exactly works. If you've any idea about it. Please help me.

Comment: @Sweeta well..to tell you frankly I haven't implemented this functionality yet. I would need to research a bit before I can help you in any way regarding this. I'll see if I can get back to you with something.PS - don't depend on my response. Keep digging :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `XMPPMessage+XEP_0085` category just define some simple methods to add chat state info, but also there are methods to **check if chat state exists** in message. So, you need to write an `XMPPModule` which will process message in `-xmppStream:... didReceiveMessage:` (note, you should use `didReceiveMessage`) and "multicast" events to others if message `hasChatState` and/or `hasComposingChatState`, etc. You can see examples of `XMPPModule` in the implementations of other XMPP extensions, e.g. `XMPPPing`